# Orgmode, Export HTML in One Shell Command

Tags: org-mode, eval-expression

When using Orgmode, we can generate/export HTML file or TXT file from ORG file, using `C-c C-e`(or `M-x org-export`), as described in https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Export-Dispatcher.html.

I wonder if possible to generate them using shell commands? like `emacs --eval org-export --target-file my-notes.org`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try...

`emacs my-notes.org --batch -l my_init_file.el -f org-latex-export-to-pdf`

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: As a supplement, I prefer no `-l` option, that is `emacs my-notes.org --batch -f org-latex-export-to-pdf`, which is more adaptive.

Comment: The point however is that `--batch` deliberately skips loading your init file, so if you have any customizations that you need for the export, you will have to use a `-l some-init-file.el`. But `some-init-file.el` can be much simpler than the full `init.el` that you use for your interactive sessions, which generally has a lot of stuff in it that is *not* relevant just for exporting an Org mode file to PDF.

Comment: See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/40957/14825